# Validar campos vacios C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET dónde valido los campos vacios que son mis textbox, lo que quiero hacer es que no se registre el usuario sin completar los campos y que al faltar datos para llenar se muestre un asterisco y un mensaje de que faltan datos, pero que al llenar ese dato faltante desparezca el asterisco y el mensaje. ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un control RequiredFieldValidator, por ejemplo, que este sea tu textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="miTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="texto" Text="" Width="85%" Enabled ="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Y este tu validador:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="miValidador" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="miTextBox"
                                        ErrorMessage="Campo Obligatorio"
                                        ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="El campo es obligatorio" ValidationGroup="miGrupoValidacion">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Y luego en el botón de registrar, agregarle esta propiedad:

```
CausesValidation="True"
```

Comment: He usado ese control pero tengo algunos campos repetidos por ejemplo: numero de tel. en el empleado y el numero de tel. del jefe, ambos se validan mostrando el mensaje: ingresa numero de tel., por lo tanto al mostrar el mensaje es con validationsummary y me muestra los dos mensajes repetidos y solo quiero que me muestre uno.

Comment: Pero deberías personalizar los mensajes entonces, porque no se refieren al mismo teléfono.

Comment: Añado, no utilizo el validationsummary, de la forma en que muestro el código, si falta un campo al momento de intentar registrar, solo muestra un asterisco rojo al lado del campo, y si posicionas el cursor encima del asterisco, muestra la descripción.

Answer (score 1):

Una de ellas y que le recomiendo es por HTML5, colocando el atributo "requered" a los campos de texto que considere deben ser obligatorio ser llenados por el usuario. Hay gran cantidad de información al respecto en la red.

```html
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

Otra forma es JavaScript y sobre eso también hay amplia información.

la ventaja que puede tener esta solución es que la validación se hace en el cliente.